# angular-google-charts: Unexpected value NaN parsing x attribute

Tags: angular, angular-material, google-visualization, nan

I have an Angular 6 service passing data to populate A Google Material Chart.

app.component.ts

```
  export class CustomersComponent implements OnInit {

  customers: Customer[];

  charts: Array<{
    title: string,
    type: string,
    data: Array<Array<string | number | {}>>,
    roles: Array<{ type: string, role: string, index?: number }>,
    columnNames?: Array<string>,
    options?: {}
   }> = [];

  @ViewChild('chart')
  chart: GoogleChartComponent;

  constructor(private customerService: CustomerService) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
 this.getCustomers();
 this.customerService.getCustomers()
 .subscribe(res => {
  //  console.log(res)
   let firstname = res.map(res => res.firstname);
   console.log(firstname)
   let age = res.map(res => res.age);
   console.log(age)

   this.charts.push({
    title: 'Customer Demographics',
    type: 'Bar',
    columnNames: ['Customer', 'Age'],
    roles: [],
    data: [
      [firstname, age],
    ],
    options: {
      chart: {
        title: 'Customer Demographics',
        subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017'
      },
      bars: 'vertical' // Required for Material Bar Charts.
    }
  });
 })}
```

Then when I try to pass the data into Google charts nothing populates and I get a Unexpected value NaN parsing x attribute error.

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the data appears to be in the wrong format.

instead of two arrays with individual column values...

```
[ "Joe", "Peter", "Lauren"...
[ 36, 18, 31...
```

each row in the data should be an array with each column value...

```
[ "Joe", 36 ],
[ "Peter", 18 ],
[ "Lauren", 31 ],
```

you should be able to correct by combining the values in your `map` statements.

replace...

```
let firstname = res.map(res => res.firstname);
let age = res.map(res => res.age);
```

with...

```
let data = res.map(res => [res.firstname, res.age]);
```

then add the data to the charts object...

```
this.charts.push({
  title: 'Customer Demographics',
  type: 'Bar',
  columnNames: ['Customer', 'Age'],
  roles: [],
  data: data,  // <-- add data here
  options: {
    chart: {
      title: 'Customer Demographics',
      subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017'
    },
    bars: 'vertical' // Required for Material Bar Charts.
  }
```

Comment: YES! This was exactly the problem. Thank you so much!